# What does 蔵を立つくらい勉強なさい mean

Tags: translation

Boy asks her mother if she could build a warehouse, mother answers:

バカなことを言う暇があったら蔵が立つくらい勉強なさい。

Which means something like "if you have time to say stupid things like this then study (as much as you build a warehouse)?"

I guess the difficult point for me here is くらい, which I guess should mean "as much as" but it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Isn't it either 蔵**が**立つくらい or 蔵を立**てる**くらい?

Comment: Oops, yes I fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## English

We don't say "蔵{くら}を立{た}つ". If we search for a similar expression to it, we say "蔵を建｛た｝てる" or "蔵が建｛た｝つ".
In Japan, "蔵を建てる" is a symbol of a rich man. In Western countries I think that it has the same meaning as "having a pool."
In general, 蔵｛くら｝ is built, on the same premises, as a building used for a warehouse separate from the residence that you usually live in.
There are roughly two main reasons why the millionaires build 蔵 as follows.
(1) In order to keep valuable items that cannot be placed in houses where you usually live. In other words, the owner of the 蔵 has more valuable items than necessary. Therefore, a dedicated warehouse to store unnecessary valuables is necessary.
(2) Since Japanese houses are basically made of wood and paper, when a fire occurs, valuable items stored in it along with the houses also burn. On the other hand, since the outer wall of a 蔵 is constructed with fire-resistant materials such as "漆喰｛しっくい｝ *cement plaster daub*", you can protect valuables stored therein against disasters such as fire.
"蔵が建つほど勉強｛べんきょう｝する" means "勉強して偉｛えら｝い人になって大金持｛おおがねも｝ちになる *To succeed in social life or realize your dream by studying hard and become a millionaire.*"

## 日本語

「蔵を立つ」とは言いません。似た表現で言うなら「蔵を建てる」あるいは「蔵が建つ」と言います。
日本では、「蔵を建てる」とは大金持ちの象徴です。欧米では「プールを持つ」と同様の意味があると思います。
一般に、蔵は普段住む住宅（or 家屋）とは別の建物として、住宅と同じ敷地内に建てますが、大金持ちが蔵を建てる理由として次のように大きく２つあります。
（１）普段生活する住宅に置ききれない置物等を含む貴重品を住宅とは別の建物である蔵に保管する。あるいは、保管専用の建物が必要なほど貴重品が多い。
（２）日本の家屋は基本的に木材と紙とで作られているので、火事が発生すると、住宅と共にその中に保管してある貴重品も燃えてしまう。一方、蔵は"漆喰｛しっくい｝ *cement plaster daub*"等の火事で燃えない材料で外壁を構築しているので、その中に保管してある貴重品を火事などの災害から守ることができる。

「蔵が建つほど勉強する」とは、「勉強して偉い人になって大金持ちになる」という意味です。